# Apply activ class on whole list group vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to apply  an active class on a list-group from a vuetify component.

The issue is that it apply the class only on the "header" of the list, not the drawer (see  Expansion Lists  list on vuetify)

```
 <v-list>
      <v-list-group
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.title"
        class="my-1 mx-2 primary--text"
        color="#F5F5F5"
        no-action
        outlined
        active-class="selected" // <<<< - not working on WHOLE group only on header !
        :append-icon="item.marker ? 'mdi-minus' : 'mdi-plus'"
        @click="item.marker = !item.marker"
      >
```

[Here is a screensot of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsUpZ.png)

What i would like is that the green border apply also on the drawer with the info but I don't understand how to achieve this

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://codepen.io/nimaebrazeh/pen/eYRGNLK?editors=101) is what you want.

You can apply `class="v-list-item--active"` to each `v-list-item`.

Comment: it was almost this but you leaded on on the right way : it was "v-list-group--active"  ! I wanted to target the whole groupe not the item but it's good thanks a lot !